# Foundation Split Button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a Zurb split button, which I am trying to get the click event FOR THE BUTTON, but not the split part [dropdown] of the button.

When I use jQuery on the link, it catches the whole link, in a way that I can't use the split button.

How can I let the split button be, and only catch the on click event of the "main" button?
I tried adding an ID to the span, but that messes up Foundation's inner works.

```
<div class="session_on"> <a href="#" id="start" class="button split">Start<span data-dropdown="drop_on"></span></a>
    <br>
    <ul id="drop_on" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$("#start").click(function () {
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to wrap your button text with another inline element. And listen on this wrapper element.

For example, you can wrap it with an

```
<a href="#" id="start" class="button split">
    <i id="start-main">Start</i>
    <span data-dropdown="drop_on"></span>
</a>
```

You need to work on the padding of this  and the parent  so that it covers the entire button you want to listen to. See the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/douglasliu/a60ex2yp/) for reference.

Comment: ended up with this:
<a href="#" id="start" class="button split"><div id="bigside">Action</div><span data-dropdown="drop_on"></span></a>

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of what you are trying to do, but as long the [span] is a part of [a] you will get the click event of [a] and all it's contents when clicking on [a].

Comment: i know! i am trying to figure out how to make the button work on zurb without the split [span] being clicked:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/split_buttons.html

Comment: As I get it from foundation this isn't intended to work this way. Why not mimic the optics with your own elements? We had this a couple of times where I work and it always ended with us building the elements needed if the framework can not provide the behaviour we want. And as you noticed yourself, messing with foundation's guts messes up things. :/

Comment: No ready-made framework is supposed to work out-of-the-box as you'd like it. The solution that was picked is a pretty elegant one, check it out! :D